# Django model get not getting the recently inserted mysql values

Tags: django, apache, django-models, python-2.7

I am running a django project in apache.
Iam inserting a form field value to table.

```
    from blog.models import Blog
    b = Blog(name='Beatles Blog', tagline='All the latest Beatles news.')
```

But when getting the inserted value by django orm iam getting error.

```
    entry = Blog.objects.get(name='Beatles Blog')
```

When restarts apache getting the inserted value.

Is this a apache cache issue or django cache issue? 
How can i get get the recently inserted value without restarting apache?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where is that get() taking place? Show the full code.

Answer (score 1):

did you save the model?

```
b.save()
```

Comment: yes i had saved using b.save(), Am getting the result on apache restart.